# How can I realise "Write to both columns" in Rails Active Record (as Strong migrations recommends)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm trying to change type of column in PostgreSQL (Rails 6).

**migration:**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ChangeUsersEmailToCitext < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    enable_extension('citext')

    change_column :users, :email, :citext
  end

  def down
    change_column :users, :email, :string
  end
end
```

But Strong Migrations throws error and says following:

```
=== Dangerous operation detected #strong_migrations ===

Changing the type of an existing column blocks reads and writes
while the entire table is rewritten. A safer approach is to:

1. Create a new column
2. Write to both columns
3. Backfill data from the old column to the new column
4. Move reads from the old column to the new column
5. Stop writing to the old column
6. Drop the old column
```

I understand the point and danger of db locking... but my question is pretty silly, and I haven't found answer on it. How literally can I make 2nd, 4th and 5th points? How can I force my ActiveRecord model write to both columns at the same time and switch after backfilling to the right one?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the old column is `length` and new column is `length_advanced`.

2 - Write to both columns

```
def length=(value)
  super(value)
  self[:length_advanced] = value
end
```

4 - Move reads from the old column to the new column

```
def length
  if super.present?
    super
  else
    self[:length_advanced]
  end
end
```

5 - Stop writing to the old column

```
def length=(value)
  # no write to old column
  self[:length_advanced] = value
end
```

More on all of this https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Answer (score 0):

In your case this should work:

```
 class ChangeUsersEmailToCitext < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
   enable_extension('citext')
   add_column :users, :new_email, :citext

  Users.reset_column_information
  Users.find_each do |record|
   record.update(
     new_email: record.email.to_citext, // make conversion here
   )
  end

  safety_assured { remove_column :users, :email }

  safety_assured { rename_column :users, :new_email, :email }
 end

 def down
   raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration, "Reverting this migration is not supported"
 end  
end
```